# After updating the page, a 404 error pops up on gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

How to get rid of the problem that after updating the page, a 404 error pops up on gh-pages. But when I refresh the main page, everything is fine, there is no error, but it is worth going to some other page and then updating it, it appears. The site is written in React

[image]

I added a 404 html file, but that doesn't help either

```
     var pathSegmentsToKeep = 1;

      var l = window.location;
      l.replace(
        l.protocol + '//' + l.hostname + (l.port ? ':' + l.port : '') +
        l.pathname.split('/').slice(0, 1 + pathSegmentsToKeep).join('/') + '/?/' +
        l.pathname.slice(1).split('/').slice(pathSegmentsToKeep).join('/').replace(/&/g, '~and~') +
        (l.search ? '&' + l.search.slice(1).replace(/&/g, '~and~') : '') +
        l.hash
      );
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not know how to help with your case but try vercel to upload your website, its easier (from my experience, at least)

Comment: I did this - 
added to <BrowserRouter> basename="/testtest" and everything worked

Comment: Please paste your code into a code block instead of images of code https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Answer (score 0):

Change `var pathSegmentsToKeep = 1;` to `var pathSegmentsToKeep = 0;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.